# Highlight cells which have specific formula

Tags: excel

How to highlight cells that have a specific formula.
E.g cells that have a formula of "vlookup".
I knew search/replace can always look into formulas. But how to look into formula for conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Edited from @Dominique suggestions and it seems working.
'=IF(FIND("VLOOKUP",FORMULATEXT(A1)),TRUE)'

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional formatting, based on this kind of formula:

```
=FIND("VLOOKUP";FORMULATEXT(...))
```

Keep in mind that `find()` seems to be case sensitive.

More elaborated: imagine you have a formula with `VLOOKUP()` in cell `B2`. On the cell you want to highlight, you can use conditional formatting (Home ribbon, Conditional formatting, Highlighting cell rules, More rules, "Use a formula"), and as a formula, you use the following:

```
=IFERROR(FIND("VLOOKUP";FORMULATEXT(B2));FALSE)>0
```

Explanation:

`FIND()` searches for the word "VLOOKUP" in cell B2 (mind the uppercase).
`FORMULATEXT()` converts the formula in normal text, and can be used as input for `FIND()`.
In case the word "VLOOKUP" is not found, an error is shown.
The `IFERROR()` function deals with the error, showing FALSE as a result.
The "greater than" check makes sure that the formula results in TRUE, enabling the formula for the conditional formatting.

Comment: Sorry I am kind of newbie for this. Can you tell me the details? How to higlight all of the cells that contain "vlookup" formulas? I tried Condtional formatting >New Rules >Use a formula to determine ... > put FIND("VLOOKUP") into the formula.

Comment: It seems like not working. I tried to copy paste your formula ="IFERROR(FIND(""VLOOKUP"";FORMULATEXT(B2));FALSE)>0"

Comment: Why do you have two double quotes (""VL...)? In your formula itself, are you using ´VLOOKUP()´ (all caps) or do you have small letters (`Vlookup()`)? I you enter this formula into a single cell, what's the outcome?

Comment: Seem like there is smth wrong with the formula. It showed "there is a problem in this formula". I tried to replace the semicolon to colon the error is gone but is is not working per what you mentioned. It always showed "True" even I changed the contents in B2

Answer (score 0):

In the below example we use:

- **"=VLOOKUP"** in column B to get the value of Column A from the range in H3:I3.
- **"=FORMULATEXT"** in Column C to get the value of Column B.
- **"=IF((IFERROR(FIND("VLOOKUP",C2,1),0))>0,"Appears","Not Appears")"** in Column E to check if words **"VLOOKUP"** appears in Column C.

**Images:**

[image]